# OracleSolaris 11.2 hostname change

Tags: configuration, solaris, opensolaris

I changed the hostname using *svccfg* and *svcadm restart* as described in https://blogs.oracle.com/VDIpier/entry/solaris_11_changing_the_hostname  however it didn't update */etc/inet/hosts* and */etc/inet/ipnodes*

Am I supposed to update those files manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `/etc/inet/hosts` (or `/etc/hosts`) and `/etc/inet/ipnodes` should be updated manually, they are relative to the network stack and not the hostname of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This blog is misleading as the commands shown are changing the `nodename`, not the `hostname`.

The `nodename` match by convention the `hostname` associated with the primary network interface (if any) but there is no requirement for them to be in sync, especially when the system uses a dynamic network configuration (`dhcp`). See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E39134/goeld.html

The `nodename` used to be stored in the `/etc/nodename` file but is now an `smf` property.

So as Thomas already replied, you need to manually edit [/etc/hosts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36882/hosts-4.html#scrolltoc), but there is no need to edit `ipnodes` which is just a link to the previous one.